# Getting a variable into the PostBackUrl of a LinkButton in a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Can anyone tell me how to get this to work please? It is a LinkButton in a row in a Gridview (in an ItemTemplate)

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbOrder" runat="server" PostBackUrl='EditOrder.aspx?OrderID=<%# Eval("OrderID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("OrderID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

It appears okay on screen. When I click it - the OrderID is not being passed.

On the EditOrder page the querystring looks like:

```
http://mysite/Orders/OrderID.aspx?OrderID=<%# Eval(\"OrderID\")%>
```

I have tried plenty of permutations of single inverted commas and double inverted commas - but I can't get the OrderID to appear in the queryString correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a post-back really necessary? I suggest you to use asp:HyperLink instead.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbOrder" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/EditOrder.aspx?OrderID={0}", Eval("OrderID"))%>' Text='<%# Eval("OrderID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Yes, a postback is necessary. I am already on EditOrder.aspx - having presented a list of orders, I want to postback so I can handle something. I can easily get it to work using the RowDataBound event of the Gridview ... I nearly always work in code behind. But I keep seeing example code of variables being written direct into controls - and it saves the hassle of doing endless 'FindControls' in the code behind .. so, is it possible to get the PostBackurl to contain a parameter?

Comment: I tried it in a sample app, and it worked. So yes, you can pass a query string parameter to PostBackUrl property. I corrected my answer to use LinkButton instead.